# tableview scroll to bottom issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a chat view in which I have used tableview, the basic feature of chat view is to show the latest messages, But table view is not scrolling to last index, it always stuck in the middle

I have around 60 messages, but it always stuck in the middle.

I already tried with
tableview.scrollToLastIndex()
tableview.scrollToIndex([IndexPath], animated: true)

but is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method [scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow)

**Example**:
tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .bottom, animated: true)